# Build rust_binary for android using bazel

Tags: android, rust, android-ndk, bazel

I can easily build `cc_binary` and execute it on android device. I want to do the same using [`rust_rules`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_rust). But not able to build it. I'm confused with flags that must be used.

I didn't try on linux, but I want to know exactly what I'm doing.

My `BUILD.bazel`:

```py
rust_binary(
    name = "hello",
    srcs = [
        "src/main.rs",
    ],
)
```

Currently I try to achieve executable rust binary with following flags (I'm on Bazel 7.0.0):

```bash
bazel build //rust:hello --android_platforms=//:android_arm64 --extra_toolchains=@androidndk//:toolchain
```

But fail with

```
external/androidndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/BUILD:8:19: in cc_toolchain_suite rule @@androidndk//toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64:cc_toolchain_suite: cc_toolchain_suite '@@androidndk//toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64:cc_toolchain_suite' does not contain a toolchain for cpu 'darwin_arm64'
```

I'm running on macOS.

Comment: `--android_platforms` is only recognized for `android_binary` and related rules, for other rules (which should include `cc_binary`) try the "regular" `--platforms`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved by adding

```
extra_target_triples = [
   "aarch64-linux-android",
],
```

to `rust_register_toolchains`.

Full answer is [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_rust/issues/2390#issuecomment-1877114113).

I was able to build and run `rust_binary` on android:

```
bazel build //:hello --platforms=//:android_arm64
adb push bazel-bin/hello /data/local/tmp
adb shell /data/local/tmp/hello
Hello world!
```